# C++ Android Key Press simulate code by pressing in app button

Tags: android, c++

I'm trying to find a simple code on the Internet, thanks to which I can simulate pressing a keyboard button when a button is pressed in a compiled application.

The problem is that I don't have "Windows.h" headers and functions like "dispatchEvent" because I have AIDE CMODS compiler. Is there a way to do this WITHOUT them?

Comment: Windows.h is not used by Android.  dispatchEvent is not an Android function.  Sounds like you're trying to code a Win32 app to run on Android-  those apps only run on Windows, no other OS.  To run an app on Android, you either need to write an app in Kotlin (or Java) using the Android SDK, or in C or C++ using the NDK.  The Kotlin route is preferred, the NDK is not user friendly and not particularly high performing since it needs to keep calling into Java (the Android API is 100% java based).   The NDK really only makes sense for very particular types of apps

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.